# установка django на windows

Tags: python, windows, django

```
Какой именно путь мне надо прописать в PYTHONPATH. 

    (li) C:\Users\Envs\li\django_li\sitetest>py -3 manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 16, in main
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

pip list:

```
    C:\Users\>pip list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    """
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .exceptions import (
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\exceptions.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves.http_client import (
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 203, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\Envs\li\Lib\site-packages\django\http\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.http.cookie import SimpleCookie, parse_cookie
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Надо перевести последние две строки ошибки, в них ответы.

Comment: Александр, спасибо поправлю.перевел, но не понял). попытался создать переменную pythonpath. Потом хотел добавить путь до джанго установленуую в env. Не сработало

Comment: запускайте как `..\env\Scripts\python.exe manage.py runserver`

Comment: @DmitryKozlov ImportError: cannot import name 'cookies' from 'http' (C:\Users\l\Envs\li\Lib\site-packages\django\http\__init__.py)
Теперь такая ошибка. Если надо могу скинуть вывод в консоль(там очень много).

Comment: вы пакеты ставили в env или глобально? Похоже, что глобально, а потом запускаете проект в env

Comment: @DmitryKozlov django ставил в env, python глобально

Comment: _cannot import name 'cookies'_ там есть `cookie`, возможно опечатка

Comment: если добавить файлу 's' в конце, то вылезает это ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.http.cookie'

Answer (score 0):

Виртуальное окружение надо предварительно активировать

```
env\Scripts\activate
```

А потом запускать

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: Разве env\Scripts\activate не тоже самое что workon имя_окружения? В любом случае попробовал, не помогло. Ошибка, что и в первом случае

Comment: @Adame покажите, что выводит `pip list`.

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: @Adame судя по добавленному, вы, во-первых, pip запустили не из виртуального окружения, а во-вторых, уже успели сломать системную установку Python. Рекомендую переустановить Python, пересоздать окружение и по новой поставить **в него** Django.

Comment: спасибо, попробую. Как лучше устанавливать python и django. Все в env или python глобально? И как вы определили, что системная установка сломана?

Comment: Python глобально, а все пакеты в виртуальные окружения. Определил потому, что `pip list` в норме никак не может приводить к исключению `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал все тоже самое через терминал в pycharm, все заработало.